# Wordpress is rewrite my htacces file. I adding a font rule

Tags: htaccess

I used webfonts in my Wordpress site. I need a rewriterule in my htacces. I put this in my htacces file:

```
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*) /mikevierwind/wp-content/themes/roots/fonts/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But when i save this htacces file. Wordpress is rewriting the htacces file and my fonts rewriterule is gone. How can i fix that?

Thank for helping!

Comment: Where in your `.htaccess` file are you adding that?

Answer (score 1):

Please change the permissions of `.htaccess` to read-only by accessing it via SFTP, SSH, cPanel 'File Manager' or whatever the tool you have.

Comment: If you do that, WordPress will have problems with the [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) and every plugin using it. WordPress needs to be able to write to the .htaccess file.

Comment: @hampusn I have yet to see a case where you need a rewritten .htaccess.

Comment: @toscho Even so, is that really a reason to discard it? Just because you doesn't use a function at this point in time, there's no telling what will happen in a week, a month or a year. Imagine the hassle not using `__()`, `_e()`, `_ex()` etc. when you later realize you need another language for the site. Mike should at least be aware of the possible problems.

Comment: You can add new permalinks for endpoints, custom post types, rewrite tags … without touching the .htaccess. The hard rewrite is needed only if you don’t use the rewrite API.

Answer (score 1):

Add the rule outside of the WordPress block.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # ...
  RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*) /mikevierwind/wp-content/themes/roots/fonts/$1 [QSA,L]
  # ...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You should also consider using the [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to do this. And read this [text about debugging the .htaccess file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Fixing_.htaccess_Generation_Issues).

**Edit:** [This topic on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210826/need-help-with-wp-rewrite-in-a-wordpress-plugin) could also be of use.